# Gluten Free Summer Ale

Tags: ale, gluten-free

My wife recently found out she has a gluten sensitivity, so sadly a number of things she loved are now off-limits.

As summer is upon us here in Boston, she today realized that Sam Adams Summer Ale is something she can no longer drink, and this was perhaps her favorite beer.

Does anyone know any good GF recipes for a beer which would be comparable to Sam Adams Summer Ale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also check out Clarity Ferm.  Its not FDA approved to reduce to FDA's definition of "Gluten Free", but it will typically drop out enough glutens (almost all of them) to avoid reaction unless it is a really serious/intense allergy if I understand correctly.

This way you can avoid brewing with sorgum, quinoa, and other equivalent PITAs, and just make any recipe you find, including Sam Adams Summer clones.

Since it is someone you care about, you may want to run some of the research/approximate dissolved glutens by her gastorenterologist/internist to see if he/she buys it.

You could also brew a batch, treat it with Clarity Ferm, and send it to a lab to check.

If you can pull this off (a distinct possibility), your stock is going through the roof.

See this thread:
[Any People with Celiacs Tried Clarity Ferm?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11413/any-people-with-celiacs-tried-clarity-ferm)

Comment: I love science... this is amazing!  I stopped by my local home brew store, to grab ingredients for my next DIPA, but I noticed a GF kit, and I got to talking to the guys there.  They set me up with a "Patriotic Summer Ale" recipe, and substituted sorgum for the wheat, with some grains of paradise and lemon/lime zest.  I am going to try this recipe just to ensure she has some beer ready for the warm weather right around the corner.  As soon as I get that batch in bottles, I am going to try the original "Patriotic Summer Ale" with Clarity Ferm and compare.  Thanks!

Comment: Also... I live in Boston, so "Patriotic Summer Ale", which is the home brew stores recipe, seems suspiciously like something that should be close to Sam Summer!

Answer (score 3):

There are many resources out there for GF home brewing.  I made a quick search and I found some good recipes and information, unfortunately I can't post more than two links..

[http://www.glutenfreehomebrewing.org](http://www.glutenfreehomebrewing.org/)