# Gluten-free brewing books?

Tags: books, gluten-free

Are there any comprehensive gluten-free brewing books? It's one thing to hack together knowledge from the many great traditional brewing books out there, but a coherent volume specifically for "beers" brewed without wheat, barley, or rye would be an excellent resource. Coverage of malting would be especially useful but isn't necessarily required.

For reference, I'm a former homebrewer (who was diagnosed with celiac disease), so I do have a grasp of basic brewing chemistry. But I'm not a chemist by any means, and one of the reasons I found brewing books so helpful is that they did a lot of the trial-and-error and hard thinking for me.

Comment: I don't know of any books specifically on that, but there are plenty of people on this website that will gladly answer any questions you have and tell you the mistakes they made and what worked for them :)

Comment: Have you looked into Clarity Ferm and it's apparent ability to remove (break down?) the gluten in regular beers?  It would be a shame to waste a lot of effort trying to make beers without barley, wheat, or rye (which will always be 2nd-rate beers IMO) if it turned out that all you needed to to was add one simple ingredient at pitching time.

Comment: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11413/any-people-with-celiacs-tried-clarity-ferm

Comment: @JeffRoe yes, and unfortunately that's still not good enough, especially since I don't have commercial-level quality control or any way to test gluten levels. I've had a reaction to Estrella Daura in the past and I've been advised not to try the other gluten-removed beers like Omission even though they _do_ have strict protocol.

Comment: @JeffRoe also I always enjoyed brewing with unconventional grains and I see it as a fun challenge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any books per se, but [HomeBrewtalk](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f164/) has a forum dedicated to the topic.